How do I change the phpmyadmin port?
After changing the port from 80 to 8033, only the page is displayed index.php . Previously, the second page of phpmyadmin was displayed. How do I display a page with phpmyadmin?
This is how I changed the port to the apatch:
$ sudo semanage port -l | grep -w http_port_t
http_port_t                    tcp      80, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 8448
$ sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/thost.conf
$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/thost.conf
<VirtualHost *:8033>
...
$ sudo vim /etc/apache2/ports.conf 
$ cat /etc/apache2/ports.conf 
...
Listen 8033
...
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
$ sudo netstat -tlpn | grep apache
tcp6       0      0 :::8033                 :::*                    LISTEN      2452/apache2 
$ sudo semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 8033
$ sudo semanage port -l | grep -w http_port_t
http_port_t                    tcp      8033, 80, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 8448
$ sudo ufw allow 8033
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
$ google-chrome http://192.168.122.98:8033/


That's what helped me
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
$ sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin.conf
$ sudo systemctl reload apache2
$ sudo apt-get install php8.1-mbstring
$ sudo cat /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini | grep extension=
...
;extension=curl
;extension=ffi
...
$ sudo vim /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini
...
;extension=curl
extension=ctype
;extension=ffi
...
$ sudo cat /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini | grep extension=
$ sudo service apache2 restart


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

To ensure that phpMyAdmin is correctly displayed after changing the port, follow these steps:

Check phpMyAdmin Configuration:
Ensure that phpMyAdmin is configured to be accessible on the new port. Update the Alias directive in the Apache configuration to reflect the new port.
$ sudo vim /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf


Make sure it looks like this:
 Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>


Restart Apache:
Restart Apache to apply the changes.
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2

Access phpMyAdmin:
Use the updated URL to access phpMyAdmin. If you are using an alias (e.g., /phpmyadmin), append it to the new port URL:
http://192.168.122.98:8033/phpmyadmin

Check Apache Logs:
If phpMyAdmin still doesn't load, check the Apache error logs for any hints:
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log

Verify Permissions:
Ensure that the phpMyAdmin directory has the correct permissions and ownership.
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/share/phpmyadmin
$ sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/share/phpmyadmin


